# One-dimensional Ising model

Tags: probability

I want to solve the following problem, which is taken from a textbook.

Consider $n$ particles located at the points $1,2, \ldots, n$. Suppose that each particle is of one of two types, and that there are $n_1$ particles of the first type and $n_2$ of the second ($n_1 + n_2 = n$). We suppose that all $n!$ arrangements of the particles are equally probable. Construct a corresponding probabilistic model and find the probability of the event $A_n(m_{11}, m_{12}, m_{21}, m_{22}) = \{ v_{11} = m_{11}, v_{12} = m_{12}, v_{21} = m_{21}, v_{22} = m_{22} \}$, where $v_{ij}$ is the number of particles of type $i$ following particles of type $j$ ($i,j = 1, 2$).

We label the $n$ particles with $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m$ and define the sample space as 
$$
\Omega := \{ \text{permutations of the set } \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m\}\},
$$
where the number of elements of $\Omega$ is $N(\Omega) = n! = (n_1 + n_2)!$. To find the probability of the event $A_n(m_{11}, m_{12}, m_{21}, m_{22})$, we have to count the number of different $n$-tuples lying in this set. At this point I have no idea how to count the elements of this set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll consider the particles in a circle and leave it to you to incorporate the annoying details that arise because they're in a row.

Then $v_{11}+v_{12}=n_1$, $v_{21}+v_{22}=n_2$ and $v_{12}=v_{21}$. Thus there is only one degree of freedom to consider, the number $k=v_{12}=v_{21}$ of switches from $1$ to $2$ and back. There are $\binom n{2k}$ ways to choose positions for the $2k$ switches from the $n$ potential positions and $2$ ways to make them from $1$ to $2$ or from $2$ to $1$. Thus

$$A(m_{11},m_{12},m_{21},m_{22})=\begin{cases}\frac{2\binom n{2m_{12}}}{\binom n{n_1}}&\text{ if }m_{11}+m_{12}=n_1, m_{21}+m_{22}=n_2, m_{12}=m_{21}\;,\\0&\text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$